# Select weekly data from date table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with date and other columns. The dates are all weekdays excluding holidays and weekends. I need to select weekly data from the table (OR every Monday data and if Monday is a holiday select Tuesday's. Next row will be Monday's data and so on.).

```
    Example table columns and data:
    Date           Rate    StockQty       
    2018/08/31      22       25 
    2018/09/04      24       25
    2018/09/05      23       24
    2018/09/06      19       21
    2018/09/07      25       22
    2018/09/10      21       21

    I need to select data such that the result will be:

    Date           Rate    StockQty       
    2018/08/31      22       25
    2018/09/04      24       25
    2018/09/10      21       21
```

It is selecting one row per week. 9/3 is Monday and a holiday, so select Tuesday date, then select next week's Monday date.

I tried to partition by DatePart, but it lupms all week together.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Date functions are notoriously database-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow logic like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by extract(year from date), extract(week from date) order by date asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Date functions can vary by database.  This uses ANSI/ISO standard functions.

Comment: I am using MS SQL. It does not have week. I can select year, month and day. I am trying to select one row per week data from a range of dates.

Comment: In SQL Server, use `DATEPART(WEEK,date)`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I only partitioned by week, adding year helped. Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    create table #Date_rate
    (
    date smalldatetime,rate int,stockQty int
    )
    Insert into #Date_rate
    select '2018/08/31',      22 ,      25  union
    select '2018/09/04',      24 ,      25  union
    select '2018/09/05',      23 ,      24  union
    select '2018/09/06',      19 ,      21  union
    select '2018/09/07',      25 ,      22  union
    select '2018/09/10',      21 ,      21

 select 
         a.date
        ,a.rate
        ,a.stockQty
    from(
        select 
             *
            ,dense_rank() over(partition by datepart(WEEK,date) order by datepart(WEEKDAY,date) asc) as SekectedDay
        from  #Date_rate
    ) a where SekectedDay=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in SQL Server:

```
SELECT date,Rate,StockQty FROM 
(SELECT
    date,
    Rate,
    StockQty,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(date),DATENAME(WK,Date) ORDER BY day(date))cnt
 FROM
    #temp
 )m
WHERE
cnt = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already selected above answer. For me, partition by year, week is what worked.